# ASSOCIATE chains in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, associate

The `ASSOCIATE` feature is in principle quite useful, as it allows assigning values to names without incurring the syntactical overhead of explicitly defining local variables. However, its utility is limited because the values are bound only *after* the `ASSOCIATE` statement. This quickly leads to the need for *nested* associate statements, e.g.

```
PROGRAM toyexample
  IMPLICIT NONE
  ASSOCIATE(a => 2)
    ASSOCIATE(b => [a, 2*a, 3*a])
      PRINT *, a
      PRINT *, b
    END ASSOCIATE
  END ASSOCIATE
END PROGRAM toyexample
```

In Lisp terms, this would be the behavior of `let`, while I seek to emulate the behavior of `let*`, which would allow me to write

```
PROGRAM toyexample
  IMPLICIT NONE
  ASSOCIATE(a => 2, b => [a, 2*a, 3*a])
    PRINT *, a
    PRINT *, b
  END ASSOCIATE
END PROGRAM toyexample
```

Is there any feature in Fortran that allows me to do this?

Comment: It depends on your compiler. For example ifort does allow what you are asking for even as it is not standard conforming.

Comment: @jack I tested and confirm. Sadly, I need to code to work across several compilers.

Comment: It is indeed the case that you cannot use the associate name in a selector in the same associate list. There are ways to force things in to one associate construct, but perhaps none is as understandable/elegant as nested associate constructs (however awkward that is).

Comment: @roygvib That solution looks more like obfuscation. It doesn't gain anything except a few typed characters, but it doesn't affect, e.g., nesting levels. Though in principle something like `#define associate3(a,b,c) ASSOCIATE(a); ASSOCIATE(b); ASSOCIATE(c)` might achieve the purpose -- but still at the cost of slight obfuscation (and confusing the editors indentation capabilities).

Comment: @kdb okay... Because current Fortran does not allow that syntax, I think it will be very nice if you post the desired behavior here (via the "issue" tab) https://github.com/j3-fortran/fortran_proposals I would also like to use that syntax if available in future.

Comment: @roygvib I wrote the suggestion now. There are several functionally competing suggestions for `let` constructs, but they have much higher complexity, so an extension of the `ASSOCIATE` construct might still be interesting. Took me only 2 1/2 years to do it :₋)

Comment: @kdb thanks for writing the proposal! (and yes, it takes time & time flies... :) I still believe such an extension (or some new variant) of `associate` would be very useful if it could provide better (and less verbose) functionality, eg, local short-hand access to many components of a nested derived type in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
program toyexample1
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: a = 11
    integer, parameter :: b = 22
    integer, parameter :: c = 33

    associate(a => b, b => c, c => a)
        print *, a, b, c ! Intel Fortran print: 22 33 22, other 22 33 11
    end associate
    block; integer, parameter :: a = b, b = c, c = a ! NAG Fortran rejected
        print *, a, b, c ! All compilers print: 22 33 22
    end block
    block; integer, parameter :: a = 2, b(*) = ([a, 2*a, 3*a]) ! PGfortran crash
        print *, a, b(:) ! All compilers print 2 2 4 6
    end block
end program toyexample1
```

Comment: Practical use-cases would not use `PARAMETER` values. The use of constants is purely for the sake of providing a minimal example.